# Sinónimo [android] ← [android-sdk]

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

### Propongo el sinónimo [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) ← [android-sdk](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sdk)

La etiqueta [android-sdk](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sdk) siempre trata sobre temas de desarrollo en [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

- Ambas etiquetas tienen prácticamente la misma wiki de etiqueta ([wiki de android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info) vs. [wiki de android-sdk](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-sdk/info))
- Actualmente sólo hay 14 preguntas en [android-sdk](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sdk), 11 también etiquetadas [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), y todas están etiquetadas así para marcar que se está desarrollando en Android.
- La etiqueta [android-sdk](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sdk) no aporta ninguna información extra ni es útil para las búsquedas. Tiene 1 solo seguidor, que probablemente también siga a [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) (que tiene 219 seguidores y 2.5k preguntas).

¿Les parece bien? Lo planteo como discusión por si hay algo que no esté considerando.

En paralelo, estoy proponiendo el sinónimo en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/synonyms para quienes puedan votar.

Comment: ahi tiene un voto :P

Comment: Ya quedó aprobado el sinónimo, felicidades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitivamente son sinónimos  [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) ← [android-sdk](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sdk).

En cuanto a la etiqueta [android-sdk](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sdk), puede existir algún issue especifico en cierta versión de sdk, por lo que tal vez sería útil si se agregara la versión, por ejemplo [android-sdk-7.0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sdk-7.0), pero lo mejor sería generalizar simplemente con la etiqueta [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

Voto por esta [propuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/synonyms).

Comment: Dudé exactamente con lo mismo, pero viendo todas las preguntas que estaban etiquetadas así, las 14 no preguntaban sobre nada específico del SDK (y ya había editado varias previamente)... En cuanto a la nueva etiqueta [tag:android-sdk-7.0], es una buena idea, sólo habría que crear una pregunta o estar atentos para reetiquetar si alguien pregunta específicamente por algo del SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Hecho. Se ha creado el sinónimo:

> [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) (etiqueta maestra) - [android-sdk](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-sdk)

Ahora la etiqueta [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tiene 3 preguntas más.

- [Exception in thread “Loading Sources” al iniciar Android SDK Manager](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48971/13558)
- [¿Error con la version de jdk xamarin android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/30477/13558)
- [Como crear un proyecto nuevo en android studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13162/13558)